# Getting a Scala Map from a Java Properties

Tags: scala, collections, dictionary, scala-java-interop

I was trying to pull environment variables into a scala script using java Iterators and / or Enumerations and realised that Dr Frankenstein might claim parentage, so I hacked the following from the ugly tree instead:

```
import java.util.Map.Entry
import System._

val propSet = getProperties().entrySet().toArray()
val props   = (0 until propSet.size).foldLeft(Map[String, String]()){(m, i) =>
  val e = propSet(i).asInstanceOf[Entry[String, String]]
  m + (e.getKey() -> e.getValue())
}
```

For example to print the said same environment

```
props.keySet.toList.sortWith(_ < _).foreach{k =>
  println(k+(" " * (30 - k.length))+" = "+props(k))
}
```

Please, please don't set about polishing this t$#d, just show me the scala gem that I'm convinced exists for this situation (i.e java Properties --> scala.Map), thanks in advance ;@)

Comment: Nope, Ruby's too cool for me, guess it was the copy of Stan Lippman's C++ Gems on the shelf that caught my eye.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scala 2.7:

```
val props = Map() ++ scala.collection.jcl.Conversions.convertMap(System.getProperties).elements
```

Though that needs some typecasting. Let me work on it a bit more.

```
val props = Map() ++ scala.collection.jcl.Conversions.convertMap(System.getProperties).elements.asInstanceOf[Iterator[(String, String)]]
```

Ok, that was easy. Let me work on 2.8 now...

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions.asMap
val props = System.getProperties() : scala.collection.mutable.Map[AnyRef, AnyRef] // or
val props = System.getProperties().asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[String, String]] : scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String] // way too many repetitions of types
val props = asMap(System.getProperties().asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[String, String]])
```

The verbosity, of course, can be decreased with a couple of imports. First of all, note that `Map` will be a mutable map on 2.8. On the bright side, if you convert back the map, you'll get the original object.

Now, I have no clue why `Properties` implements `Map<Object, Object>`, given that the javadocs clearly state that key and value are `String`, but there you go. Having to typecast this makes the implicit option much less attractive. This being the case, the alternative is the most concise of them.

**EDIT**

Scala 2.8 just acquired an implicit conversion from `Properties` to `mutable.Map[String,String]`, which makes most of that code moot.

Comment: As a side note, this is the first time I do Java <-> Scala collection conversions. The last time I tried I wasn't experienced enough to get it to work. And not only did I get the chance to overcome my previous defeat, but I find this particular problem of much interest, as I find myself now and then perusing the system properties!

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I'll give your answer a proper look later. I'm pleased to have provoked your interest in this topic.

Comment: @Daniel, I suspect that this is the gem I was looking for, just a shame about the cast, especially as Properties should implement Map[String, String]. These conversions are a great find for me.

Comment: Just to make clear, the cast is Java's implementation of Properties' fault, not Scala's.

Comment: Daniel, the Chaotic Good Elf Mage defeats the old, gnarly, villainous beast which is the Java Properties construct.  Sorry, but your first comment reminded me of an RPG...

Comment: No problem, but I'm more of a lawful good dwarf fighter, even if I do look like an elf. :-)

Comment: This answer is outdated (as it goes with Scala unfortunately)

Answer (score 8):

Scala 2.10.3

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

//Create a variable to store the properties in
val props = new Properties

//Open a file stream to read the file
val fileStream = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName))
props.load(fileStream)
fileStream.close()

//Print the contents of the properties file as a map
println(props.asScala.toMap)
```

Comment: Hi Sarath. Thanks for contributing to the site. We prefer answers on StackOverflow to have a bit more explanation than just posting code. Try reading this [guide to posting good answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more help :)

Answer (score 7):

In Scala 2.9.1 this is solved by implicit conversions inside collection.JavaConversions._ . The other answers use deprecated functions. The details are documented [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_46.html). This is a relevant snippet out of that page:

```
scala> import collection.JavaConversions._  
import collection.JavaConversions._

scala> import collection.mutable._
import collection.mutable._
scala> val jul: java.util.List[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3)
jul: java.util.List[Int] = [1, 2, 3]
scala> val buf: Seq[Int] = jul
buf: scala.collection.mutable.Seq[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3)
scala> val m: java.util.Map[String, Int] = HashMap("abc" -> 1, "hello" -> 2)
m: java.util.Map[String,Int] = {hello=2, abc=1}
```

Getting from a mutable map to an immutable map is a matter of calling toMap on it.

Comment: Thanks for the update, Daniel did provide an edit to his answer mentioning these implicits. Ironically enough accessing the environment is going to be even more straightforward in scala 2.10, just use the immutable map returned by the sys.env method.

Comment: Just realised that it was a conversion for properties to a Scala Map I'd asked for, however Scala 2.10 also has a sys.props method to access the system properties as well.

Comment: The edit in Daniels answer is about Scala 2.8, and it has changed again in 2.9... I know it's confusing.

Answer (score 4):

In Scala 2.8.1 you can do it with `asScalaMap(m : java.util.Map[A, B])` in a more concise way:

```
var props = asScalaMap(System.getProperties())

props.keySet.toList.sortWith(_ < _).foreach { k =>
  println(k + (" " * (30 - k.length)) + " = " + props(k))
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vitalii, I took a look at asScalaMap and there's also version of asScalaMap which allows an implicit conversion from a java Properties instance to a Scala mutable Map[String, String].

Answer (score 2):

In Scala 2.13.2:

```
import scala.jdk.javaapi.CollectionConverters._

val props = asScala(System.getProperties)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like in the most recent version of Scala (2.10.2 as of the time of this answer), the preferred way to do this is using the explicit `.asScala` from `scala.collection.JavaConverters`:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val props = System.getProperties().asScala

assert(props.isInstanceOf[Map[String, String]])
```

Comment: This is the best answer IMO. Thanks.